# Webbrowser не способен отобразить reCAPTCHA

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Можно как то заставить компонент Webbrowser1 отобразить reCAPTCHA ? В моем случае страница просто загружается а reCAPTCHA нет.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('Ссылка на сайт');
WebBrowser1.Silent := True;
```

Comment: Он старый, но капча там раньше работала...

Comment: Без понятия. Может её просто подключить не смогли.

Comment: Этот компонент устарел. Используйте CEF4Delphi: [Встраивание браузера Chromium в Delphi приложения](http://www.proghouse.ru/programming/146-chromium-delphi)

Comment: TWebBrowser использует встроенный в Windows InternetExplorer. Соответственно, если ваш системный IE сможет правильно показать нужную страницу, то и в Delphi должно получиться (но только на данном конкретном компьютере).

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вот этот совет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518118

Comment: @zed, я так понимаю по ссылке код вставлять после implementation

{$R *.dfm}. Сделала но в OnCreate формы не вижу вот TBrowserEmulationAdjuster.SetBrowserEmulationDWORD(TBrowserEmulationAdjuster.IE11_Quirks);

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. неправильно отображалась версия IE в Webbrowser. Решение вопроса:

Вносим правки в реестр и все работает как нужно.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"Project1.exe"=dword:10001
```